# Sending base class over json and converting to parent class on client side

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, signalr

I have two classes `Group` and `Contact`.

They both extend my base class `ChatTarget`.

I am using Signalr to send these objects to my clients.  My server sends and my client endpoints expect a `ChatTarget` object.  On the server, I am able to cast back and forth from `Contact` or `Group` to `ChatTarget`.

After sending my `ChatTarget` down to my client, I am no longer able to convert a `ChatTarget` to any of its extended classes.  It appears that the json serialization is destroying the extended properties and maintaining only the base `ChatTarget` stuff.

How can I retain the ability to cast a `ChatTarget` back on my client side?

Comment: How many potential child types will you have?  You have a Group and Contact.  Do you foresee an unlimited amount of other child types?  One thing you can consider is doing a composite model to pass back.  For exmaple `public class ChatTargetResponse { public GroupTarget Group { get; set; } public ContactTarget Contact { get; set; } }` Doing this, you have two explicit children -- one for each target kind -- and thus no confusion.  If one is null, the other will not be, i.e. mutually exclusive.  There are potentially other methods, but this way ensures strongly-typed responses on both sides.

Comment: Thanks. This probably would work for me. I will have more but not an unlimited amount. Still, I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: As an aside, Eli's solution makes it harder for cross-platform stuff, since any custom deserialization now has to look a level deeper and do a bunch of null checks.

Comment: you must've misunderstood then. The point of this is to make it more cross-platform friendly, as you can know, with confidence, what the fields are (i.e. strongly typed).  If you created a strongly-typed stub in other platforms, you'd have to do conditional deserialization based on, say, a "Type" field to know which properties to deserialize.  My method keeps it strongly-typed no matter the platform.  If the fields of a response type don't matter, there are other "anonymous type" options (e.g. straight JSON document iterating).  Or using a dictionary for "extra" paremters specific to subtypes.